# CSV to Object converter with JavaDoc comments

Tags: java, android, csv

This is a simple class but I'm looking to check I have the basics down to scratch.

Is my documentation thorough enough? (I'm very new to writing JavaDoc) Have I created too many variables, and does this sacrifice performance for readability in a bad way?

This class is called once to create an array of `TestDataObjects` to use with our `Parsing` unit tests.

```
    /**
 * Converts our test data csv in to an ArrayList
 * We divide the csv entries up line by line for each calendar event then create a TestData object from each line.
 * The fields we wish to parse have negated new line characters to ensure they don't interfere with the csv parsing.
 * Once the csv has been parsed we need to unnegate these so the test data is the same as the original data.
 * @param calendar The csv to convert
 * @return An Array List of TestData objects that have all the three fields we wish to parse and the correct results we wish to obtain.
 */
private ArrayList<TestData> loadTestData(String calendar) {
    ArrayList<TestData> testDataArray = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] lines = calendar.split("\r\n");

    // always skip lines[0] as it contains the headers
    for (int i = 1; i < lines.length; ++i) {
        ArrayList<String> fields = CSVReader.parseLine(lines[i]);
        String title = fields.get(0).replace("\\n", "\n");
        String location = fields.get(1).replace("\\n", "\n");
        String description = fields.get(2).replace("\\n", "\n");
        ArrayList<String> correctHostCodes = CSVReader.parseLine(fields.get(3));
        ArrayList<String> correctParticipantCodes = CSVReader.parseLine(fields.get(4));
        ArrayList<String> correctPhoneNumbers = CSVReader.parseLine(fields.get(5));

        TestData testDataObject = new TestData(title + "\n" + location + "\n" + description, correctHostCodes, correctParticipantCodes, correctPhoneNumbers);
        testDataArray.add(testDataObject);
    }

    return testDataArray;
}
```

Comment: Are you using opencsv for parsing the line i.e. CSVReader.parseLine? Would you like to handle any IOException in this method?

Comment: @notionquest My colleague built the CSVReader I think it's based off of this.
https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/

Comment: @notionquest As for the IOException, I'm not sure, what would the benefits be to catching it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### OS-dependent line separator

You can use [`System.lineSeparator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator--) to retrieve the correct OS-dependent line separator `String`, instead of hard-coding `\r\n`.

#### Method parameters

```
private ArrayList<TestData> loadTestData(String calendar) {
    // ...
}
```

`calendar` does not sound like it's supposed to be CSV data. You can consider calling it just `data`, or `events` to relate it closer to your use case.

#### Interfaces over implementations for documentation too

On a related note to [@mdfst13](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/139186/24141)'s answer, the use of `List` (or 'list') should be preferred over `ArrayList` (or 'Array List') for similar reasons.

1. Should the implementation type change in the future, your Javadoc is not rendered outdated.
2. Typically, the implementation classes' names are less 'English'-like than the interfaces, so it's easier to understand lists and maps, instead of 'Array List' and 'Hash Maps'. :)

#### HTML and Javadoc tags

Be sure to use some simple HTML tags to aid in the eventual layout you see in your IDE/browser. In addition, the `javadoc` tool itself understands some tags, such as the [`{@link package.class}`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#CHDDIECH) that automatically creates a link to the target class.

#### Knowing your audience

You use a great deal of our/us in the Javadoc, presumably to establish some sort of a rapport with the end-user using this code. There's nothing inherently wrong with this. :)

However, I can't recall any public Javadocs out there written from the first-person perspective, so I can't comment (pun intended) whether this is a bad practice or not.

In any case, I suppose cutting down on such pronouns makes the Javadoc shorter and to-the-point. For example:

```
/**
 * Converts test data from CSV format to a list.<br>
 * Line-by-line calendar events are converted to individual {@link TestData} objects.<br>
 * Negated new line characters in the fields to parse are un-negated so that the test data
 * is the same as the original.
 *
 * @param events The data to convert, in CSV format.
 * @return A {@link List} of {@link TestData} objects with all fields to parse and the
 *         correct results to obtain.
 */
```

Comment: Am I right to describe the `TestData` within the `javadoc` `@return` statement for this method when the user could just click the link to the `TestData` documentation?

Comment: It's useful as a direct link within this method's Javadoc, the user may be viewing the no-frames version of the Javadoc. ;)

Answer (score 3):

#### Prefer interfaces to implementations

> ```
> private ArrayList<TestData> loadTestData(String calendar) {
>     ArrayList<TestData> testDataArray = new ArrayList<>();
> ```

and

> ```
>         ArrayList<String> fields = CSVReader.parseLine(lines[i]);
> ```

and

> ```
>         ArrayList<String> correctHostCodes = CSVReader.parseLine(fields.get(3));
>         ArrayList<String> correctParticipantCodes = CSVReader.parseLine(fields.get(4));
>         ArrayList<String> correctPhoneNumbers = CSVReader.parseLine(fields.get(5));
> ```

You would normally write these as

```
private List<TestData> loadTestData(String calendar) {
    List<TestData> testDataArray = new ArrayList<>();
```

and

```
        List<String> fields = CSVReader.parseLine(lines[i]);
```

and

```
        List<String> correctHostCodes = CSVReader.parseLine(fields.get(3));
        List<String> correctParticipantCodes = CSVReader.parseLine(fields.get(4));
        List<String> correctPhoneNumbers = CSVReader.parseLine(fields.get(5));
```

That way, even if `parseLine` changes its return type, you don't have to change unless it changes to something that doesn't implement the `List` interface.

#### Range-based `for` loops

> ```
>     String[] lines = calendar.split("\r\n");
>
>     // always skip lines[0] as it contains the headers
>     for (int i = 1; i < lines.length; ++i) {
>         ArrayList<String> fields = CSVReader.parseLine(lines[i]);
> ```

You could rewrite this as

```
    List<String> lines = Arrays.asList(calendar.split("\r\n"));

    // always skip lines[0] as it contains the headers
    for (String line : lines.sublist(1, lines.size())) {
        List<String> fields = CSVReader.parseLine(line);
```

Or not.  If you find the indexed form easier to follow, that works too.